# Angularjs showing 500 internal server error on posting data to laravel routes

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-routing, angularjs-routing, angularjs-http

For some reason I'm getting a 500 interval server error when posting data from angular to laravel route.

app.js

```
var quora = angular.module("quora-app", ['q-controller-1', 'ngRoute', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = "XMLHttpRequest";
}]);
```

My controller

```
angular.module("q-controller-1",[])
    .controller("q-master-1",['$scope','$location','$http',function ($scope,$location,$http) {
        $scope.update=function(value,text) {
            $scope.id=value;
            $scope.putText=text;
        }
        $scope.info=[]
        $scope.cancel=function() {
            $location.path("/");
        }
        $scope.validate=function(updateInfo) {
            if($scope.update.$valid) {
                $scope.info.push({
                   id:$scope.id,
                   question:updateInfo.qText
                });
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/update',
                    data: $scope.info
                })
                .success(function () {
                   console.log('true');
                })
                .error(function(){
                    console.log('false');
                })
            }
        }
    }]);
```

My router file

```
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'api'], function() {
Route::post('/update', ['uses' => 'questionController@update']);});
```

Log Error

```
angular.min.js:103 POST http://localhost/quora/public/api/update 500 (Internal Server Error)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:103n @ angular.min.js:99(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:96(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:131$eval @ angular.min.js:145$digest @ angular.min.js:142$apply @ angular.min.js:146(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:276dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
qaController.js:29 false
```

How do I work around it?

Comment: 500 error means that there is something rong in the server side so you must take a look in your server Log file !

Comment: you should check your `laravel.log` file in `storage/logs` directory.

Comment: yes im getting this error: `local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::json() should not be called statically`. what does it mean?

Comment: I think you use `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` you should use this facade instead `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;` !

Comment: show us the questionController@update